Retrieving a single value scalar from a PostgreSQL function using EF Core 8
I have a function in PostgreSQL that returns a single integer:
SELECT runtime.get_accessible_instance_count(...)

This returns the number in PGAdmin.
I want to use this function in EF Core, I have tried like this:
return await runtime.Database
       .SqlQueryRaw<int>("SELECT runtime.get_accessible_instance_count(@....)", parameterArray)
       .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

Unfortunately, I get an exception:

Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42703: column t.Value does not exist POSITION: 8

It turns out, that EF Core translates this to:
SELECT t."Value"
FROM (
    SELECT runtime.get_accessible_instance_count(@...)
) AS t
LIMIT 2

And sure, there is no column. I can work it around by adding an as "Value" at the end.
But that's not how it should work I suppose...

From here EF queries: However, since your SQL becomes a subquery whose output column needs to be referenced by the SQL EF adds, you must name the output column Value.
